# @font-face defined in __layout.svelte not accessible from form elements in components?

Tags: css, font-face, svelte, svelte-component, sveltekit

I have a SvelteKit project where I add a custom `@font-face`, which is applied to `*` as shown below, inside a `<style>` tag in `__layout.svelte`

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Inter';
    src: url('/inter.woff2') format('woff2-variations');
}
* {
    font-family: 'Inter', 'Fira Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
}
```

Most content is displayed as expected in Inter, including `<label>`s inside components. However, form elements in components (`<input>`, `<button>`) fall back to Fira Sans (which I have installed locally). Other than `font-size`, no additional font styling is applied inside the components.

How would I apply the custom font to these elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the globally access css in `app.css`.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Inter';
    src: url('/inter.woff2') format('woff2-variations');
}
* {
    font-family: 'Inter', 'Fira Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
}
```